# Why ECMAscript 6 Object.freeze not working with Locker Service?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

We have a library we created using ECMACScript 6 that we transpiled using babel that worked perfectly with a VisualForce page. Migrating this library to work with Locker Service I found that Object.freeze is not working. I will like to understand why and know if there is an equivalent way to do this that works with Locker Service.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [Freeze JavaScript Prototypes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_freeze_prototypes.htm)

Comment: Could you provide some sample code we could look at?

Comment: @JFParadis seems in fact it works. Sorry!!! I'm kind of new to Locker Service. It was already hard for me sometimes to understand Lightning Components errors and despite the fact I had years working with Javascript is really hard to debug and understand what is going on. I still had error I know now is not there but will ask once I have a better understanding. Thanks.

Comment: @ymiki Perfect, let us know how we can improve.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the Locker Console to prototype your code:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console

It's a great way to understand how Locker works.